# Get function key (name) used when calling Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to be able to identify the key (ideally key name) provided in the header (x-functions-key) for the POST to the Azure Function in the Run method, e.g.

```
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
```

It is great to be able to protect access to the Azure Function adding Function Keys in the Azure Portal panel, but I must be able to tell which function key was used. Ideally it would be possible to associate claims on each function key, but as long as I can at least figure out which key was used I will be happy.

Comment: POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}/listsecrets?api-version=2016-08-01

Comment: My azure function uses AuthorizationLevel.Function which means a function key must be provided in the header that matches one of the Function Keys set in the Azure Portal panel under "Manage". It is a great way to control access to an azure function, but I need to verify which vendor the provided key belongs to at runtime. I have not discovered any way to see which key was used. Not suprisingly there are no identities in ClaimsPrincipal principal.

Comment: Instead of getting the key name I can always just get the key from the header directly from the header:
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues values;
bool result = req.Headers.TryGetValue("x-functions-key", out values);

This is less ideal, but a simple solution to identify access based on the key.

Answer (score 8):

Simply get the claim "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid" from the req.HttpContext.User.Claims object. It contains the key id in case a Function key was used.

Works like a charm, and does not require external lookups.

```
const string KEY_CLAIM = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid";
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var claim = req.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == KEY_CLAIM);
    if (claim == null) 
    {
        log.LogError("Something went SUPER wrong");
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
    else
    {
        log.LogInformation( "Processing call from {callSource}", claim.Value);
    }
```

Comment: is this still current? - i mean the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid`

Comment: Yes, it's still valid, as of today (08/04/2023) the claim uri is still `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid` 

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Functions v1:

```cs
[FunctionName("MyAuthenticatedFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyAuthenticatedFunction([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function)] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage reqMsg, ILogger log)
{
    if (reqMsg.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_AzureFunctionsKeyId", out object val))
        log.LogInformation($"MS_AzureFunctionsKeyId: {val}");  
}
```

Code reference: [WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Filters/AuthorizationLevelAttribute.cs#L77](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/38231675d444b6421bef1039da4be5dda0f2fcca/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Filters/AuthorizationLevelAttribute.cs#L77)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested here's a custom extension that uses the Claim as noted in prior answers to get the App Key Name easily from the User `ClaimsPrincipal` in Azure Functions.

I believe this works with all version but has been tested with Az Func v4.

```
/// <summary>
/// Read the current Azure Function App Key Name (the name of the token as configured in azure portal).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userPrincipal"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetCurrentAzFuncAppTokenKeyName(this ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal)
{
    const string AzFuncKeyClaimUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2017/07/functions/claims/keyid";
    var claim = userPrincipal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AzFuncKeyClaimUri);
    return claim?.Value;
}
```

Usage would be:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(DoTheThing))]
public Task<SystemInfoModel> DoTheThing(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, HttpTrigger.Get, Route = "do-the-thing")] HttpRequest httpRequest
)
{
    var azFuncKeyName = httpRequest.HttpContext.User.GetCurrentAzFuncAppTokenKeyName()
                        ?? throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Azure Function Key Name claim was not found.");

    //Do all the things....
}
```